# Ingest multiple files from storage using Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I exported about 60 millions rows using the `.export` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/export-data-to-storage) to a storage as my KQL script below:

```
.export async to json (h@"https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/oversub/adx/VmCounterFiveMinutes/2023-05-20;storage-account-access-key") <|
contosoEntity
```

I removed sentity parts from my query, but the exportation works fine. It exported **192 file(s), total of 62374652 rows**.

I also need to import into another Kusto cluster, how can I use the `.ingest` command from storage to ingest all `.json` files from a specific folder from storage?

If there any other better solution to ingest back to another Kusto cluster, I will be glad to know.

What I tried and failed:

1-

```
.ingest into table VmCounterFiveMinuteRoleInstanceCentralBondTable_2 (h@'https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/oversub/adx/VmCounterFiveMinutes/2023-05-20/*.json;storage-account-access-key')
```

2-

```
.ingest into table VmCounterFiveMinuteRoleInstanceCentralBondTable_2 (h@'https://contoso.blob.core.windows.net/oversub/adx/VmCounterFiveMinutes/2023-05-20/*.ext;storage-account-access-key')
    with (format='json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't specify a wildcarded (`*`) path when running the (unrecommended) direct ingestion command (`.ingest`).

you could use [LightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest) or the [Ingestion wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-from-local-file) to ingest the files you've exported (with filters on blob name prefix, if required)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line tool called "[lightingest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest)" or use the [OneClick wizard tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-explorer/ingest-data/data-explorer-ingest-data-one-click) in Kusto Web explorer